# Can receiving console input be considered a console event?

Tags: c, winapi, events, console, keystroke

For example, if a server has to reread a particular configuration file every time a specific console event occurs, pressing a key on the keyboard (suppose the 'q' key) can be considered a console event?

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events) help?

Comment: @PaulSanders The problem is that I do not want a passive wait.
Initially I did this thing simply by using a control handler that managed the ctrl + break signal, but handling this signal causes me a problem with the wsaduplicatesocket function.
For the moment I'm using the kbhit () function, before accepting a new client I do this:
while (kbhit ())
{
     if (getch () == 'q') change config ...
}
kbhit is non-blocking and returns 1 if you have pressed a key on the keyboard (I put it in a while because you could press other keys, but I need q)
What do you think about it?

Comment: Sounds like a busy loop to me.  I suggest you post your code as an edit to your question, and read how to create a [MCVE]